# Get original view definition from POSTGRESQL DB

Tags: view, postgresql-9.5

I have created a view with the below definition :

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id int,name varchar);
INSERT INTO t1 values(1,'n1'),(2,'n2');
CREATE VIEW v2 AS SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE name = 'n1';
```

But when i checked the definition in postgresql DB(9.5) in pg_views table, it is getting modified in the below way :

```
postgres=# select * from pg_views where schemaname = 'sc1' and viewname = 'v2';
     schemaname | viewname | viewowner |               definition
    ------------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------
     sc1        | v2       | postgres  |  SELECT t1.id,                         +
                |          |           |     t1.name                            +
                |          |           |    FROM sc1.t1                         +
                |          |           |   WHERE ((t1.name)::text = 'n1'::text);
    (1 row)
```

I am fine with adding tablename before columnname but i don't want the extra '::text' part. 
Is there anyway to achieve this(like any other system table i can query from to get original definition)

Comment: Just take the source code out of your version control system.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, do u mean getting source code of postgresql and modifying? can u please elaborate on this

Comment: No, I mean **your** source code. You should have the original CREATE VIEW statement in **your** version control system.

Comment: yes, in our source code we have some parsing rules for select query of CREATE VIEW statement where ':: text', these r not allowed and i don't want to change these existing ones as it might disrupt other queries. so i had 2 options in my find : 1.Get original definition from postgres 2.Modify the definition we get from postgresql. FYI : we won't store definition in ours, we just get these info from postgresql itself using jdbc connection.

Comment: "*Get original definition from postgres*" is simply not possible, when you create a view, it is parsed by Postgres and **only** the parsed version is stored. You **have** to get it from your version control system (git, subversion, ...). Not managing your code in a version control system is a really, really bad idea to begin with (and this is only one example on why it's a bad idea)

Answer (score 2):

You can **not** get the "original" view definition from the Postgres system tables. 
Postgres **only** stores the parsed version.